# RxJava/Android monitor progress of multiple subscribers fired at different times

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am looking for a way, hopefully using RxJava for consistency, to monitor the progress of multiple subscribers that may be fired at different times. I am aware of how to merge or flatMap subscribers together when they are all fired from one method but I am unaware of a way to do it when they are fired at different times from different methods.

For example, if I have 2 long running tasks attached to button presses. I push button 1 and fire off the observable/subscriber, half way through running I push button 2 to fire off the second observable/subscriber.

I want to enable a button when no tasks are running and disable it when one or more tasks are running.

Is this possible? I am trying to avoid setting instance variable flags as well.

Comment: in your example, you would start by subscribing to both your buttons in the same place, and possibly use something like `combineLatest` to get event from them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a separate `BehaviorSubject` and `scan` to monitor execution status. This is quite similar to an instance variable, but probably it can inspire you to a better solution. Something like this:

```
private final BehaviorSubject<Integer> mProgressSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(0);

public  Observable<String> firstLongRunningOperations() {
    return Observable.just("First")
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> mProgressSubject.onNext(1))
            .finallyDo(() -> mProgressSubject.onNext(-1)));
}

public  Observable<String> secondLongRunningOperations() {
    return Observable.just("Second")
            .doOnSubscribe(() -> mProgressSubject.onNext(1))
            .finallyDo(() -> mProgressSubject.onNext(-1));
}

public Observable<Boolean> isOperationInProgress() {
    return mProgressSubject.asObservable()
            .scan((sum, item) -> sum + item)
            .map(sum -> sum > 0);
}
```

Usage will be like this:

```
isOperationInProgress()
        .subscribe(inProgress -> {
            if (inProgress) {
                //disable controls
            } else {
                //enable controls
            }
        });
```

With this approach you can have any number of long running operation and you do not have to fire them all. Just don't forget to call `doOnSubscribe` and `finallyDo`.

PS. Sorry, I didn't test it, but it should work.

Comment: Wrapped the implementation up into its own class and it worked well. Thanks!

Comment: What is BehaviorSubject?

Answer (score 1):

To make this possible, let both long running operations emit an onNext event on a PublishSubject. Combine both Subjects with a zip or combineLatest function and subscribe to this. Once the combine function receives an event, this means that both Subjects have emitted an onNext event, thus both long running operations have finished and you can enable the 3rd button.

```
private PublishSubject<Boolean> firstSubject = PublishSubject.create();
private PublishSubject<Boolean> secondSubject = PublishSubject.create();

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    subscribeToResult();
}

private Observable<Integer> firstOperation() { 
    return Observable.just(100)
                .delay(1000) // takes a while
                .subscribe(tick -> firstSubject.onNext(true));
}

private Observable<Integer> firstOperation() { 
    return Observable.just(200)
                .delay(1000) // takes a while
                .subscribe(tick -> secondSubject.onNext(true));
}

private void subscribeToResult() {
    Observable.zip(
        firstSubject,
        secondSubject,
        (firstResult, secondResult) -> return true
    ).subscribe(
        tick -> thirdButton.setEnabled(true)
    )
}
```

Definitely take a look at the RxJava combine functions.

Comment: I like the idea. Would it still work in the case that the second button was never pushed?

Comment: zip will only emit if all enclosed Observables have emitted an item, combineLatest will also only emit the latest value of all Observables after each observable has at least emitted one value. So in your case, the 3rd button would only be enabled after both long operations have finished.

Comment: I need to handle the case where button 2 is never pushed. Basically I want the button enabled when no tasks are running and disabled when tasks are running. I should have made that more clear in my initial question, will edit it now.